# Reference request: Construction of Lebesgue integral through supremum of a normalize linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am auditing a course on integration and they are constructing the Lebesgue integral in a way I am not familiar with.

It appears they are defining a normalized linear functional $l$ on $C([0,1])$ where $l(1)=1$. And the Lebesgue integral will apparently work out to be 
$$
\sup_{c\in C([0,1])}l(c)
$$
I understand this is rather vague, I was just hoping I could crowd source and see if it rings a bell. Other information I remember is that partitions of unity appear important and a process similar to the completion of a metric space is happening. I am hoping for a book that follows a similar process to define $\int_0^1\mathrm dx$

Comment: This is a particular case of (one of the) Riesz representation theorems, see Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis ch 2 for the topological prelims including partitions of unity and for the full proof.